# Filter pandas dataframe with SequenceMatcher

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difflib

When I filter the data frame using the the code below, it works fine

```
my_df.loc[lambda x:x["name"]=="space"]
```

When I filter using the following code, it gives an error

```
my_df.loc[lambda x: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,"email",x["name"]).ratio()>0.8]
```

I want to filter using `SequenceMatcher` and maybe using more complex condition than the above one

Here is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import difflib
my_df=pd.DataFrame({"name":["space","mapp","eemail","daata"],"id":[9,12,13,14]})
my_df.loc[lambda x:x["name"]=="space"] #this line works
my_df.loc[lambda x: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,"email",x["name"]).ratio()>0.8] #this doesn't
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
my_df.loc[my_df['name'].apply(lambda x: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,"email",x).ratio()) > 0.8]
```

Output:

```
    id  name
2   13  eemail
```